# Complete rings with respect to an I-adic topology

Tags: ring-theory, local-rings

I am interested in a ring $R$ with an ideal $I\subset R$ and the following properties:
1) $R$ is complete with respect to $I$-adic topology;
2) $\cap_{n\geq 1} I^n=\{0\}$;
3) $R/I$ is finite. In particular, I am interested in the case when $I$ is principal.

Is there classification/description/characterization of such rings and ideals?